# Play console internal test app not compatible with any device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing, device-compatibility

I'm building a mobile app in Unity and have been doing internal tests with Play Console for well over a year. However, a few weeks ago, all devices stopped being compatible with the app, showing a 'Your device is not compatible with this version" message. I do not know what changed, and I'm stumped as to what it may be.
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.DragonFederationIncorporated.DragonFederationAR"
    platformBuildVersionCode="33"
    platformBuildVersionName="13"
    android:compileSdkVersion="33"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="13"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="7220"
    android:versionName="7.22" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="24"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.home_screen"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.ar.core" />

        <provider android:authorities="org.khronos.openxr.runtime_broker;org.khronos.openxr.system_runtime_broker" />

        <intent>
            <action android:name="org.khronos.openxr.OpenXRRuntimeService" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="org.khronos.openxr.OpenXRApiLayerService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="org.khronos.openxr.permission.OPENXR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.khronos.openxr.permission.OPENXR_SYSTEM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.vr.headtracking"
        android:required="true"
        android:version="1" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window"
            android:value="False" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="notch.config"
            android:value="portrait|landscape" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.auto-report-fully-drawn"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="com.oculus.intent.category.VR" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="notch_support"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.oculus.vr.focusaware"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core"
            android:value="required" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackExtractionService"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.versionCode"
                android:value="20002" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ExtractionForegroundService"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.PlayCore.Transparent" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version"
            android:value="220920000" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.oculus.supportedDevices"
            android:value="quest|quest2|cambria" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationManager"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationRestartReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.exact_scheduling"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="reschedule_notifications_on_restart"
            android:value="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```